# Linq Select properties based on property names in list at runtime

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list of objects, eg

```
List<CustomClass> dataList = new List<CustomClass>
{
    new CustomClass { Field1 = "a1", Field2 = "a2", Field3 = "a3", Field4 = "a4", Field5 = "a5"},
    new CustomClass { Field1 = "b1", Field2 = "b2", Field3 = "b3", Field4 = "b4", Field5 = "b5"},
    new CustomClass { Field1 = "c1", Field2 = "c2", Field3 = "c3", Field4 = "c4", Field5 = "c5"},
    new CustomClass { Field1 = "d1", Field2 = "d2", Field3 = "d3", Field4 = "d4", Field5 = "d5"},
};

public class CustomClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

and a list of selected property names, eg

```
List<string> propertiesSelectedList = new List<string> { "Field1", "Field3", "Field5" };
```

How can I dynamically `Select` only the required properties at runtime using LINQ?

Eg equivalent of the following but at runtime using the values in list `propertiesSelectedList`?

```
var newListWithSelectedProperties = dataList.Select(n => new { n.Field1, n.Field3, n.Field5 }).ToList();
```

The final output would hopefully would look like this list...

```
List<T> newdataList = new List<T>
{
    new T { Field1 = "a1", Field3 = "a3", Field5 = "a5"},
    new T { Field1 = "b1", Field3 = "b3", Field5 = "b5"},
    new T { Field1 = "c1", Field3 = "c3", Field5 = "c5"},
    new T { Field1 = "d1", Field3 = "d3", Field5 = "d5"},
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263862/c-sharp-create-object-with-dynamic-properties-linq-select-listobject-values). This uses a combination of `Linq` and `ExpandoObject`, which I think would suit your needs.

Comment: do you intend to have anonymous objects as the resulting collection? is this on purpose or did you write it because you don't know how else to demonstrate what you want?

Comment: @MongZhu I don't know how to demonstrate what I want. I just want to limit the new list to fields contained in a List<string>.

Comment: do you want the result to be a flat list? or do you still want that the values `"Field1", "Field3", "Field5"` of each object are preserved as a group?

Comment: I've updated my question to show desired output object.

Comment: You have said "Required" properties. How do you want to determine the required properties? Are you going the decorate the properties with RequiredAttribute?

so do you want the out a list of object according to your  example output or list of strings ?

Comment: I don't mean RequiredAttribute, I just mean the 'required' properties (or desired properties) will be listed in `List<string> propertiesSelectedList = new List<string> { "Field1", "Field3", "Field5" };`

Comment: ok, then it seems that you have to work with a dynamic type like in the duplicate.

Comment: @codein - I think you've misunderstood. I don't want this in the where filtering clause but in Select to specify returned properties. It looks like the duplicate links provided will get me to where I can do this. Thanks everyone.

Comment: yes. just realized. that's I removed the comment. thanks