# Select specific columns in a generic repository function

Tags: c#, linq, repository-pattern

We want to create a generic function which will select only required columns rather than returning the whole entity. For example I have a Country class which 
has the following properties.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CountryId { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
public int CreatedBy {get;set;}
public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
```

And I have a Respiratory Class which is common for all entities.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    DbContext db;
    DbSet<T> currentEntity;
    public Repository(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        currentEntity = db.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T TEntity)
    {
        currentEntity.Add(TEntity);
    } 


    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return currentEntity.ToList<T>();
    }
}
```

As `GetAll` method is returning all columns, but I want to select only `Name` and `CountryId`. How can I create a generic function which would be returning only required data?

Comment: In C# that would mean you have to return anonymous types or dynamic types from your repository. I don't think you should want that, do you? It may be better to return `IQueryable<T>` instead of `List<T>` so the consumer can apply projections efficiently.

Comment: Yes I want to return dynamic types from my repository. Can i use generic delegate like Action<> and pass it to Linq's Select method to create an anonymous type object which will be containing only two properties of the country entity.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First you need added generic method in to generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    DbContext db;
    DbSet<T> currentEntity;
    public Repository(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        currentEntity = db.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T TEntity)
    {
        currentEntity.Add(TEntity);
    } 


    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return currentEntity.ToList<T>();
    }

    public ICollection<TType> Get<TType>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, Expression<Func<T, TType>> select) where TType : class
    {
        return currentEntity.Where(where).Select(select).ToList();
    }
}
```

now, you can called this method. Example:

```
public void SomeService()
{
    var myData = Repository.Get(x => x.CountryId > 0, x => new { x.CountryId, x.Name });
    foreach (var item in myData)
    {
        var id = item.CountryId;
        var name = item.Name;
        // ... 
    }
}
```

And last - you need runtime create lambda expression and runtime get Required fields. Maybe this post help you : [Create a lambda expression with a new anonymous type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838136/create-a-lambda-expression-with-a-new-anonymous-type-at-runtime), and [How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime)
p.s. sory for my bad english =)

Comment: What if I only want to get, for example, the Id Column? I've created the method with this signature public ICollection<int> GetIds(Expression<Func<TEntity,int>> select) but when I write:

        private static void DoMigrate<T,R>(ISource<T> sourceService, IDestination<R> destinationService, IParser<T,R> parser) where T : class where R : class
        {
...
List<int> addedIds = destinationService.GetIds(x => x.Id);
...
}

I get 'R doesn't contains a definition for Id'

Comment: Maybe you need write '{ .. where R: HasId }' instead '{ .. where R: class}', where HasId - class with Id property, and also you need use inheritance from HasId  for target classes

Comment: Right! After read a lot about that It was the option I've took

Answer (score -3):

Declare a DTO class:

```
public class Getdata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And use like this..

```
public virtual List<Getdata> GetAll()
{
    var countrys = db.currentEntity.ToList();
    var data = (from f in countrys
                select new Getdata
                {
                    Id = f.CountryId,
                    Name = f.CountryName
                 }).ToList();
    return data;
}
```