# EF Core: how to use Include in generic repository?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 classes, `Client`, `Payee` and `LookupFile`, and I'm planning to use a generic repository pattern to work with the database.

The `LookupFile` and `Payee` always have a `Client` associated with them.

When querying for a `LookupFile` or `Payee`, I want to include the related `Client` so I included the `Client` object in the base entity.
Now this is creating a self referencing key in the `Client` table when I run migrations.

How do I go about not having a self referencing `Client` table and also be able to include the related `Client` record when querying the `LookupFile` and `Payee`?

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; } //Added client object so it be used in include
}

public class Payee : BaseEntity
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string PayeeName { get; set; }
}

public class LookupFile : BaseEntity
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public class Client : BaseEntity
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
}

// Then my GenericRepository is defined as below:
public class DataRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DataRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>()
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .Include(c => c.Client)
                             .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer, don't use the generic Repository (anti-)pattern.
The more complete answer, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760405/modifying-existing-generic-repository-pattern-to-add-select/70762122#70762122

Comment: Thank you. I stopped inheriting Base Entity for the Client and made a separate Client specific repository.

Comment: Even better, don't use repositories, `DbContext` already provides abstracted data access ;)